# How do I correctly install PyQt5 module against Intel Python 3.6.x (64 bit)?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am attempting to install the module PyQt5 against my Intel Python 3.6 installation running on a 64 bit Windows 10 OS. PyQt5 5.12 is installed correctly (as far as I can tell) via pip, however I am getting the below error when running my code. I understand that Intel Python 3.6 is a 64 bit application and that the error means that PyQt5 is 32 bit...however I'm not sure what to do about it.

I have the reference Python 3.7 installed and fully working with PyQt5. I have another version of PyQt5 installed elsewhere on my system. Is it possible that my dll files are linked to this other installation?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File 
 "C:/Users/my_username/PycharmProjects/iAnalysis/venv/gui/hypergeometric_calculator.py", line 16, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: I've attempted to force Python to run in 32 bit mode by setting compatibility mode to the oldest Vista mode available, however that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that as of June 2019 Intel Python is not compatible with PyQt5 and therefore there is no answer to this question at the moment.